# How to make Scilab open a serial communication with /dev/ttyACM0 USB port in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication, scilab

I'm trying to open a serial communication between [Scilab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab) and Arduino. However, Arduino is always recognized by Linux Ubuntu in the `/dev/tty**ACM0**` port. When I write `h=openserial(1,"9600,n,8,1)` in Scilab I know that I'm saying to it, to open a serial comunication to `COM1` or `/dev/tty**S0**` in Linux.

But, for example, if I use `h=openserial(N,"9600,n,8,1)`, assuming `N=port number`, I will always have COMN, in Windows and `/dev/tty**S**(N-1)` in Linux.

How do I open a serial comunication through `/dev/tty**ACM0**` port in Scilab for Linux?

Comment: I rewrote the serial communication library from scratch to make it comparable with the MATLAB features, please find the prototype [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/44fe9b5e2bcb02b22392adf6d8f7a871).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`openserial.sci`](https://github.com/sengupta/Scilab-Serial/blob/master/macros/openserial.sci) from the [Serial Communication Toolbox for Scilab](https://github.com/sengupta/Scilab-Serial) repo,

```
function h=openserial(p,smode,translation,handshake,xchar,timeout)
//port name
  if ~exists("p","local") then p=1; end
  if type(p)==1 | type(p)==8 then
    if p<=0 then error("port number must be greater than zero"); end
    if getos() == "Windows" then
      port="COM"+string(p)+":"
    else
      port="/dev/ttyS"+string(p-1)
    end
  elseif type(p)==10
     port=p
  else
     error("port to open must be either a number or a string")
  end
```

The port is always set to `/dev/ttyS<PORT_NUMBER>`. So in your local toolbox files, you could try editing the following lines in `openserial.sci` to something like this:

```
function h=openserial(p,smode,translation,handshake,xchar,timeout)
//port name
  if ~exists("p","local") then p=1; end
  if type(p)==1 | type(p)==8 then
    if p<=0 then error("port number must be greater than zero"); end
    if getos() == "Windows" then
      port="COM"+string(p)+":"
    else
      port="/dev/ttyS"+string(p-1)
    end
  elseif type(p)==10
     port=p
  elseif type(p)=="ACM0"
     port="/dev/ttyACM0"
  else
     error("port to open must be either a number or a string")
  end
```

and then call openserial as follows:

```
h=openserial("ACM0","9600,n,8,1)
```

Also make sure that `/dev/ttyACM0` is the correct device node. This is a sample output from `ls -l`, that you can run to confirm:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Mar 12 18:16 /dev/ttyACM0
```

If you're getting errors opening the serial port as a regular user, you might add yourself to the correct group. Based on the above example, the group name is `dialout` on my openSUSE distro. It might be different on yours, so substitute that group name in the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <USER_NAME>
```

Comment: Tuxdude,I did what you sugest and I get the following messenger:!--error 999 
TCL_EvalStr,  at line 1
 couldn't open "ACM0": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open ACM0 r+"
    invoked from within
"set porthandle [open ACM0 r+]"
at line      17 of function openserial called by :  
h=openserial("ACM0","9600,n,8,1")

Comment: @FabioSilva - Are you sure your serial port device node is `/dev/ttyACM0` ?

Comment: @FabioSilva - Have updated the answer with more information regarding a possible permissions issue as a regular user. But your error message `no such file or directory` indicates the device node is incorrect.

Comment: Even following all the steps, I still have the same error message. To solve my problem and fit in my needs, I'm now using Octave, and it works very well. I think this is really a bug of Scilab or the Serial toolbox. Anyway, thank you for the help.Regards.

Comment: any idea where scilab installs the atom?

Comment: OK, on Windows it is on `C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\Scilab\scilab-6.0.2\atoms\x64\serial\0.4.2\macros` I was able to find this using `which` command.

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
h = openserial("/dev/ttyACM0", "9600, n, 8, 1");
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

keep simple, STRINGS its a valid option to port, so as Luis post:

"...Just type:

```
h = openserial("/dev/ttyACM0", "9600, n, 8, 1");
```

and you are done..."

As an example, supouse your arduino its on serial port "/dev/ttyACM0" type on Scilab:

```
n=300 // plot 300 data points from serial port "/dev/ttyACM0"
h=openserial("/dev/ttySACM0","9600,n,8,1")
i=1;
while i<=n
data(i) = strtod(readserial(h)); // char to number
plot(i,data(i),'b-o'); // real time plot
drawnow(); // show data
i=i+1;
end
```