# Scilab - real time plot from serial port

Tags: serial-port, real-time, send, scilab

I am trying to make a program in SciLab that would make a real time plot from data received from serial port. 
My idea is to execute new *plot* function after every single portion of data received. But I think it is too much work for the computer and SciLab will not work properly and miss data.

Do you know some option to plot real time data from serial COM port? SciLab or another free program?

Comment: What's about using strings? You can cast the type with string(n) and send this.  [Maybe this posting helps you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527818/how-to-make-scilab-open-a-serial-communication-with-dev-ttyacm0-usb-port-in-lin)

Comment: Probably it is the only possibility - strings. Than you for respond. I will change the question now.

Comment: You checked the manual of the [serial communication toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial)? For real-time-graphs you should use XCOS-Blocks! You will find communication-blocks, which can be connected to a scope. Because the code is open, you can modify the blocks as you want.

Comment: For those who end up here. I' also trying to implement the MATLAB's serial port functionality [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/44fe9b5e2bcb02b22392adf6d8f7a871).

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to implement such a hardware setup run from a Scilab session that plots live data.
We do it @ENSIM, for practicals in optics: we move a translation actuator step by step (Scilab driver @ https://fileexchange.scilab.org/toolboxes/255000, plugged to port#1), and for each step we read a transmitted signal with an optical powermeter (driver @ https://fileexchange.scilab.org/toolboxes/223000, plugged to port#2). The refresh frequency of the powermeter is 1-2 Hz. So no problem to get a live plot of received data.

As well, we have written a Scilab driver for the very popular M38XR multimeter (@ https://fileexchange.scilab.org/toolboxes/232000). A syntax is implemented to continuously display the live data coming from the multimeter (same low refresh rate ~1Hz).
Etc.

2 new Scilab drivers to come soon for new instruments (a furnace, and another popular multimeter). All our drivers presently on FileExchange will be updated for Scilab 6 and gathered in a single ATOMS module (then easier to document and maintain).